# OOP Design - protected member not used in own class - but used only in sub classes

Tags: c++, oop

I have a class(names as example):

```
class Animal
{
public:
  // some virtual methods
};
```

There are also some sub-classes.

```
class Dog : public Animal
{
public:
  Dog(Map&);
  // methods - using m_Map
private:
  Map& m_Map;  
};


class Elephant : public Animal
{
public:
  Elephant(Map&);
  // methods - using m_Map
private:
  Map& m_Map;  
};
```

As you can see, when creating Dog and Elephant objects, Map reference must be provided, and these classes uses it. There are a lot of more similar sub classes of Animal(Dog, Elephant, Mouse, Cat, and more...) - all uses Map object.

All sub-classes of Animal uses Map object, I was thinking about if it would be good idea to add it to Animal class as protected member, for example:

```
class Animal
{
public:
  Animal(Map&);
  // some virtual methods
protected:
  Map& m_Map;
};

class Dog : public Animal
{
public:
  Dog(Map& map) : Animal(map);
  // methods - using Animal::m_Map
};

class Elephant : public Animal
{
public:
  Elephant(Map& map) : Animal(map);
  // methods - using Animal::m_Map  
};
```

However, Animal class will never use Map object, so it seems for me a bit not natural to store it here - for only sub-classes usage.

On the other hand, all sub-classes of Animal will use Map object - so it would be good to indicate it in Animal class. And also I have feeling that code is duplicated when I define it as member in all sub-classes.

What do you think about it? Should Map object be defined as member in all sub-classes, or only in Animal class?

Comment: The reference to external state is a design small. But apart from that, capturing a commonality as base class functionality is OK. That's what base classes are for.

Comment: This is a better question to post to programmers.stackexchange.com as it's mostly offtopic for SO.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: "The reference to external state is a design smell" - well, what are methods to avoid it?

Comment: If this map is intrinsic to every `Animal` (it seems to be), it's reasonable to have it as a protected attribute in `Animal`.

Comment: @xaxxon when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: You should prefer storing pointers as data members, not references. Storing a reference messes with `operator=`.

Comment: @Cheers I store reference as data member when I want to indicate that referenced object will always exist. Pointer can be null. So I don't  agree with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the semantic links in between animals and maps.

Since you are in C++, then you can use multiple inheritance.

First, implement a `MapWrapper` class:

```
class MapWrapper {
  private:
    Map *theMap;
  public:
    ...
};
```

and then construct your animals like this:

```
class Dog : public Animal, private MapWrapper {
};
```

Note that `private` inheritance is not generalization/specialization, just a trick to implement some kind of strong composition.

Another possibility is to introduce an intermediate class in between `Animal` and `Dog`.  `Animal` is probably a pure abstract class or a contract, so it is probably not fair to modify it for pragmatic purposes. Just introduce an `AnimalMap`:

```
class AnimalMap : public Animal {
  // everything for the map
};
class Dog : public AnimalMap {
};
```

Comment: Could you explain me first example? What MapWrapper would contain, methods operating on the map, or just accessor of Map object? I don't completly understand this idea

Comment: As you like, you can see it as an adapter that fit your needs or a very simple wrapper that let you access the map inside.

Answer (score 0):

If a variable or function is required for all derived types of a base type, then that variable or function should be a part of the base type. This is the very premise of inheritance - de-duplication of code in a logical and systematic manner.

You mentioned that you are struggling with the fact that an Animal object will never actually use a Map. Have you considered a design of your type hierarchy which involves Animal being an abstract class? This means that an Animal would never be instantiated. This makes sense conceptually in the given example - no animal is an animal alone; the category of animal encompasses many other, more specific concepts such as a dog or cat.

I would suggest that this implementation fits your example and resolves your philosophical conundrum.

Answer (score 0):

The map object would be defined in animal class only.why because you are inherit animal class properties for all your sub classes.

it is a advantage , you can create object for animal class ,and you can access the map until you did not have any pure virtual methods in animal class

when it comes to memory size of an object,there is no difference where you are holding the map ,whether in a in a base class or derived class.the size of an derived object will be same only

```
class animal
{
        public:
                int animal_id;
                int animal_age;
};
class dog :public animal
{
        public:
                int dog_type_id;
};
int main()
{
        dog d1;
        animal a1;
        cout<<"sizeof d1:"<<sizeof(d1)<<endl;
        cout<<"sizeof a1:"<<sizeof(a1)<<endl;
        return 0;
}
```